# How to make a list of Binary numbers a list of Dotted Decimal Numbers?

Tags: python, list, binary, decimal

I have this list in python that looks like this

```
mylist=[10000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 0, 10000010 00000000 01000000 00000000 0,10000010 00000000 10000000 00000000 1,10000010 00000000 11000000 000000000 1]
```

and a list of slash numbers for each binary number.

```
slashes=[14,13,14,14]
```

I need to transform the list into slash notation like this with a link number after the range.

```
mylist=[130.0.0.0/14 0, 130.0.64.0/13 0,......]
```

I am struggling to find code to transform the list as so.  I can make all the spaces periods, but then I cannot change the binary to decimal.

Comment: Its a networking question. So, search for it first. What have you tried so far?

Comment: `int('10001001', 2)`?

Comment: that slash notation is called CIDR notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> mylist
['10000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 0', '10000010 00000000 01000000 00000000 0', '10000010 00000000 10000000 00000000 1', '10000010 00000000 11000000 000000000 1']
>>> slashes
[14, 13, 14, 14]
```

Here is 1 way:

```
>>> ['.'.join(j[0][:4])+"/"+str(j[1])+" "+j[0][4] for j in list(zip([[str(int(i, 2)) for i in  item.split()] for item in mylist], slashes))]
['130.0.0.0/14 0', '130.0.64.0/13 0', '130.0.128.0/14 1', '130.0.192.0/14 1']
```

or

```
>>> list(map(lambda x:'.'.join(x[0][:4])+"/"+str(x[1])+" "+x[0][4], list(zip([[str(int(i, 2)) for i in  item.split()] for item in mylist], slashes))))
['130.0.0.0/14 0', '130.0.64.0/13 0', '130.0.128.0/14 1', '130.0.192.0/14 1']
```

Here is what happens in the intermediate steps

```
>>> [[str(int(i, 2)) for i in  item.split()] for item in mylist]
[['130', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['130', '0', '64', '0', '0'], ['130', '0', '128', '0', '1'], ['130', '0', '192', '0', '1']]
>>> list(zip([[str(int(i, 2)) for i in  item.split()] for item in mylist], slashes))
[(['130', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 14), (['130', '0', '64', '0', '0'], 13), (['130', '0', '128', '0', '1'], 14), (['130', '0', '192', '0', '1'], 14)]
>>>
```